# Errors When trying to Update SQL Field

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi All I have the following MSSQL update query

```
UPDATE Campaign **c**
**INNER JOIN** (
    SELECT CampaignID, sum(Amount) as total
    FROM Donation
    GROUP BY CampaignID
) t ON c.CampaignID = t.CampaignID
SET c.AmountDonated = t.total
```

It looks like it should work fine, however I am getting an error with the suffix for the Campaign Table (c) and then an error for the INNER in INNER JOIN, I don't understand why though. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: If you have a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#l-specifying-a-table-alias-as-the-target-object) you'll see your syntax is *very* wrong.

Comment: So it would seem

Answer (score 1):

Please, try this query:

```
UPDATE c
SET c.AmountDonated = t.total
FROM Campaign c
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT CampaignID, sum(Amount) as total
    FROM Donation
    GROUP BY CampaignID
) t ON c.CampaignID = t.CampaignID
```

Use `FROM` and `JOINS` at end of query.

Comment: Hi Marko - that worked fine, I was confused as I picked up the code from a previous answered question. Thanks for the reply

Comment: @Davea no problem. But next time check documentation for basic things. Please mark my reply as corrected answer.